# Foreign key default value

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, default-value

I have a master table and another table with foreign key. I can easily add data to master table. But whenever I want to add data to the connected table, I get a message saying Foreign key doesn't have a default value. When I make the foreign key auto increment in MySQL then I can enter data, but it is not the way it should work. May be it can be acceptable for one to one relationship.
Shouldn't the connected table get the value from Master table? or is there sth else I'm missing here?

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are saying here. Assume the following:

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT
( a int not null primary key );

CREATE TABLE CHILD
( b int not null primary key
, a int not null 
,    constraint fk foreign key (a) 
         references PARENT (a) );

insert into PARENT (a) values (1),(2);

-- What should the default value of a be?
insert into CHILD (b) values (1);
```

A foreign key is a rule that makes sure that you use a valid value for the column(s) involved. If you want a default value for a in CHILD you can add another constraint (I'm not sure why default values are considered to be constraints):

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD
( b int not null primary key
, a int DEFAULT 1 not null 
,    constraint fk foreign key (a) 
         references PARENT (a) );
```

Without that it is impossible for the DBMS to know what you mean when you don't provide a value for an attribute.

EDIT: Add info on how to retrieve last generated value

If you want to inspect what was generated in the PARENT table, and use that value for the CHILD table, you can use a function LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT
( a int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key
, c int not null );

CREATE TABLE CHILD
( b int not null primary key
, a int DEFAULT 1 not null 
,    constraint fk foreign key (a) 
         references PARENT (a) );

insert into PARENT (c) values (1);
insert into CHILD (b,a) select 1, LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

or

```
insert into CHILD (b,a) values (2, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: MySQL will silently ignore the foreign keys the way you defined them. You need to define them as a separate constraint, not inline with the column.

Comment: The mysql tag was added after my post, but I'll update my answer

Comment: I added the tag because the question stated MySQL ;)

Comment: So you actually read the questions, perhaps I should try that too ;-)

Comment: I'm saying that how should I pass the value of primary key to foreign key InnoDB with MySQL? I read about the triggers and some other possible options. I just asssumed that by connecting two tables and assigning Primary and Foreign keys, tables can exchange the key data. But apparently i have to create a trigger or pass the value of PK to FK some other way. So, any helps?

Comment: I've added info of LAST_INSERT_ID(), does that help?

Comment: @Lennart - let me try that please..

Comment: Tables can not magically "exchange" values. When you are inserting a row in the child table, the server cannot guess which parent value you want it to be connected to. If it's the last inserted value by the same session, you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, as Lennart rightly suggests. Triggers are not suitable here.